# How to unbind all keybindings that start by a specific prefix?

Tags: key-bindings, prefix-keys

I want to fully define my own `C-c` keymap, but some modes add default keybindings under that prefix. For example, I have `C-c C-c` for `rustic-mode` bindings and `C-c &` for `yasnippet` bindings. How can I unbind anything that starts with `C-c`? I've tried:

- `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c") nil)`
- `general.el`'s `(general-unbind "C-c")`

But none of them work. I've also tried unbinding specific bindings such as with `(general-unbind "C-c C-c c")` but it didn't work either.

Comment: This seems like an X-Y problem. You don't need to unbind existing keybindings to replace them with your own; just put your own bindings in a separate keymap, and then set `overriding-local-map` as needed.

Comment: Revising that advice: `use-local-map` combined with `set-keymap-parent` will likely work better

Comment: You're not wrong, but the main problem is that `which-key` shows all predefined mappings (on which I have no interest, since I prefer my own) and they clutter the hints, making it harder for me to find my own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to suppress all the local bindings starting with <kbd>C-c</kbd>, the following will do that:

```
(define-key (current-local-map) (kbd "C-c") nil)
```

Of course you'll need to add that to the startup hook for every mode where you want to do that.

(this kind of thing is why I put almost all my personal bindings on <kbd>C-z</kbd>)

Comment: Seems cumbersome and unreliable... but I'm convinced it's the best solution. Maybe I'll put mine on C-z too